# How to fix a ubuntu vm that is not booting after upgrade

Tags: kernel

I have a virtualbox ubuntu vm running on mac host.
I ran the following commands in preparation of installing mysql.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After this my vm stopped booting giving me a 
`Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init`
message.

I have used Boot-Repair to repair the vm.

And it has uploaded a file at this location with information about the problem with the vm.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24420258/

Can anyone help me with this? much appreciated.
I really don't want to trash my vm.

VirtualBox version is

> 5.1.20 r114629 (Qt5.6.2)

[Here is a screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87VrX.png)

Comment: Found an older post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867591/how-to-solve-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-without-er#19839356) that seems to point towards selinux. I have had similar issues but I always take snapshots that I can restore to. Might be a good idea to start takin snapshots in virtualbox in preparation for something like this.

Comment: I had a momentary brain freeze, I should have take a snapshot before the update.

Comment: I can boot via the live CD and can see the file system, how do i fix stuff from there.

Comment: Is that all the error says or is there more to it ?

Comment: @nullmeta I have added screenshot that shows the error.

Comment: @all after struggling for this for sometime the only conclusion I can come to is, as I am sure everyone knows, that you have to backup regularly, create a snapshot before an upgrade. Luckily for me I was able to replace the vdi file from my timemachine backup. As it turns out, there is something wrong with my current ubuntu install. I will post a different question for that problem.